# Update DropDown - Using Jquery and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can I dynamically update this dropdown, so that by clicking another button, through ng-click () I can change and update to the `<li><a data-action="100">100</a>`

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
    <li aria-selected="true" class="active">
        <a data-action="10" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">10</a>
    </li>
    <li aria-selected="false">
        <a data-action="25" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">25</a>
    </li>
    <li aria-selected="false">
        <a data-action="50" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">50</a>
    </li>
    <li aria-selected="false">
        <a data-action="100" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button">100</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean can you please clarify your question.

Comment: I would recommend to you to not use JQuery along with AngularJs, the very purpose of AngularJs is to do what JQuery did. [here](https://medium.com/@mattdionis/dom-manipulation-the-angular-way-custom-directives-d2559aa98580) is a tutorial about DOM manipulation using AngularJS

Comment: I want when clicking a button, I can dynamically change the dropdown to `<li> <a date-action="100"> 100 </a>`

Comment: Use the [AngularUI dropdown directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!dropdown), a component written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a collection of objects in your controller and manipulate them with functions.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ddlController">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="option in options" aria-selected="isSelected(option)" ng-class="{'active': isSelected(option)}">
           <a data-action="{{option.action}}" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-button" ng-click="select(option)">{{option.action}}"</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <button ng-click="select100()">Select 100</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 function ddlController($scope) {
  $scope.options = [{
    action: 10
  }, {
    action: 25
  }, {
    action: 50
  }, {
    action: 100
  }];
  $scope.selected = $scope.options[0];

  $scope.isSelected = function(option) {
    if (option.action === $scope.selected.action) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  $scope.select = function(option) {
    $scope.selected = option;
  };

  $scope.select100 = function() {
    $scope.selected = $scope.options.find(o => o.action === 100);
  };
}
```

or check this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/VictorSDK/40wdtavp/